# Is there a way to capture the screen as real-time video?

Tags: android, screen-capture

I need to make a video as a demo for one application I have developed. I know that there are some experimental applications that use DDMS and achieve a framerate of 5-6 FPS. This framerate is completely insufficient for my purposes since the application has smooth animations that I would like to show. Is there a way to do a real-time screen capture on Android? Should I settle for a capture of the emulator or a real video done with a real camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the ready solutions, the one that provides the highest quality is beagle board or some other board with DVI or S-Video out. Second best is emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, some phones provide TV video output. That seems to be the case of my Galaxy S i9000, which has a "TV Out" setting, providing video output via the Jack (TRRS) connector. Some HTC phones (Droid Incredible) may also support such video output. Then, all that is needed is a small S-Video acquisition card to capture the output.

I haven't tested that yet, but it is [reported to work](http://androidandme.com/2010/07/news/samsung-captivate-galaxy-s-video-out-demonstration/), and should allow to demo all features including multi-touch gestures, which could be hard to reproduce on a beagle board with a mouse plugged in... Plus, the phones have everything installed out of the box, that saves time.

**EDIT - 19 Sep 2011:**

Unfortunately, using the Samsung S GT-I9000 video output didn't provide good results. I purchased the specific Samsung video cable plus a Terratec G3 video acquisition USB adapter, and the results were not satisfying. The video was flickering, the image was of pretty bad quality, and it wasn't good enough for creating a demo of my app which relies on OpenGL.

So, I purchased a JVC GZ-HM435 camcorder, which records in HD, and that was a lot better. I was able to create a pretty nice video, with very acceptable quality, by positioning the camcorder appropriately using a proper stand. Also, this method better demonstrates the interactivity of the application, because one can see fingers, pinching and all that. It really shows how it works.

Comment: The HTC Evo 4G has an HDMI output port.

Comment: I've just added an edit. Now that I've quite a lot tested the TV out, I don't recommend it. A good camcorder with a stand is a lot better IMO.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know if it was a problem with the encoding (the Terratec) or the TV output.  Recording HD video isn't an easy problem, and that seems like a pretty inexpensive device. Of course, it's probably not interesting for most android devs if you have to spend €1000 on the hardware to record TV-out.  And good point about fingers, pinching, rotating, etc.

Comment: I can't really tell. One thing though: I have fast OpenGL animations, which became very blurred with the TV-out method. But I think it could be acceptable for apps which do not rely on such high frame rates. Also, in addition to pinching, etc.. the camcorder method shows the interaction with physical buttons. It's important because my demo video partly plays the role of a tutorial. I think it's pretty useful for Android newbies in general. It's "hands-on" :-)

Comment: I had the same issue (poor quality) capturing video from my Samsung Galaxy S Captivate with two different USB capture devices (Pinnacle and Dazzle). However when I plugged the phone directly into a TV the picture was crystal-clear, proving the problem is the capture device, not the phone.